# Asp.Net Repeater loses data on postback

Tags: asp.net, postback, repeater

My problem is a bit more complicated than the title says:

I made a user control (I called it editor) for editing Data base data into another user control I also made(I called it GridView).

The editor is use for each row (a row is also a usercontrol and the editor is only inside row even for insert) inside my gridview and work perfectly but not when I try to use it to insert.

The only difference between insert and edit is this Field:

```
    #region Field
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    //public Field Field { get { return DataItem as Field; } }
    private Field _field;
    [Bindable(true)]
    public Field Field
    {
        get
        {
            if (IsInsert && _field == null)
            {
                _field = SubscriptionController.CreateField();
            }
            return _field;
        }
        set { _field = value; }
    }
    #endregion
```

Inside this Field I've the collection I bind to the repeater
the `SubscriptionController.CreateField();` method just create an instance of Field class and all collection inside here is the code:

```
    public Field CreateField()
    {
        Field field = new Field();
        field.Type = GetFieldTypes().First();
        field.Label = new LocalizedStringCollection();
        field.Values = new FieldValueCollection();
        field.Selections = new FieldSelectionCollection();
        foreach (Models.TrainingGroup trainingGroup in GetTrainingGroup())
        {
            foreach (Models.Division division in GetDivisions())
            {
                foreach (Models.ProfilStatusGroup profilStatusGroup in GetProfilStatusGroup())
                {
                    field.Selections.Add(new Models.FieldSelection() { Selected = false, DivisionId = division.Id, ProfilStatusGroupId = profilStatusGroup.Id, TrainingGroupId = trainingGroup.Id });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

the collection I bind is stored in viewstate :

```
    #region FieldValues
    /// <summary>
    /// Get/Set FieldValues from Viewstate
    /// </summary>
    public FieldValueCollection FieldValues
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["FieldValues"] == null)
            {
                if (Field != null && Field.Values != null)
                    ViewState.Add("FieldValues", Field.Values);
                else
                    ViewState.Add("FieldValues", new FieldValueCollection());
            }
            if (ViewState["FieldValues"] != null)
            {
                return (FieldValueCollection)ViewState["FieldValues"];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            if (ViewState["FieldValues"] == null)
            {
                ViewState.Add("FieldValues", value);
            }
            else
            {
                ViewState["FieldValues"] = value;
            }

        }
    }
    #endregion
```

but when I get on postback all textboxes inside my repeater are empty.

Comment: I bind data to repeater on page load because the Field is bind after on init event so i need to wait page load event

Comment: Is this question still relevant?